# File or folder access in bitnami magento

Tags: magento2.2

Installed Magento Application in WMware from bitnami.

Initial setup is working fine and access with IP **`192.168.0.113.`**

I am wondering, How can I access files/folder from local machine.

Is this possible to open folder in Editor for smooth theme building?

Any Help Would be appreciated.

Comment: Which folders you can see inside bitnami folder?

Comment: I am going to develop the theme, is this possible to map 'app' folder?

Comment: Using bitnami, I don't think so. You can check bitnami forums on how to change document root.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Yes, we can use SFTP or use SSH to access file. But I am looking for development perspective. It really annoy to do some change then use SFTP to upload file.
Is there any other way to use magento for development,  which will be fast, ( configure on XAMPP/laragon/WAMP usually are very slow )

Comment: I am using CentOS with 8 GB RAM, and my Magento 2 is running much faster than running the same configuration with windows OS. I have no caching configured till now.